# Root finding using Galois theory

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Is there a method in Galois theory that, say given an $n$th degree polynomial with integer coefficients

$$a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$$

and $\alpha_1$ is a root of said polynomial, gives another root than can be found using group theoretical techniques? This is clearly true for polynomials irreducible in $\mathbb{R}$ but reducible in $\mathbb{C}$ since many of those come in conjugate pairs but is there a more general method for finding another root using the field operations?

Comment: I doubt it. If you find a root $r$, without any additional information all you can say is that the other roots will be roots of the quotient of $a_0 +\cdots+a_nx^n$ by $x-r$, in whichever field said roots exist. Therefore the problem is equivalent to finding roots for any polynomial of degree $n-1$.